# og:image com imagem do banco - symfony php

Tags: php

Oi, eu tenho uma página de notícias que o usuário pode curtir e compartilhar as notícias. Cada notícia tem a sua imagem específica. Em algumas notícias há um album de fotos espefícico. Quando há o album para a notícia, o compartilhar do facebook pega uma imagem do album e não a imagem da notícia.

Pesquisei por ai e achei que devo utilizar a meta tag og:image, mas só que não estou consegui fazer isso, olha só o meu código

a imagem é inserida na tabela da noticia.
no action:

```
$this->imagem = Doctrine_core::getTable('tbnews')
                ->createQuery('im')
                ->select('im.id, im.imagem')
                ->where("im.imagem != ''")
                ->andWhere('im.id = ', $request->getParameter('id'))
        ->limit(1)
        ->execute();

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->addMeta("og:image", "http://www.meusite.gov.br/upload/noticias/<?php echo $this->imagem;");
```

e é isso que eu tenho como resposta na renderização da página:

```
<meta content="http://www.meusite.gov.br/upload/noticias/<?php echo <pre> Doctrine_Collection data : Array( 0 : Object(tbNews) ) </pre>; ?>" name="og:image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Troque o:

```
$response->addMeta(
    "og:image",
    "http://www.meusite.gov.br/upload/noticias/<?php echo $this->imagem;"
);
```

... por:

```
$response->addMeta(
    "og:image",
    "http://www.meusite.gov.br/upload/noticias/" . $this->imagem->getAtributo()
);
```

No exemplo acima eu usei um método `getAtributo()` (que provavelmente não existe) da classe `tbnews` para imprimir esse atributo na meta tag. Troque o método por outro de sua preferência.

Comment: eu obtive isso com resposta: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine_Collection::getImagem(). E isso que aparece no html: <meta content="http://www.meusite.gov.br/upload/noticias/" name="og:image">

Comment: A sua query retorna uma coleção de entidades, e não apenas uma única entidade. Você precisa pegar o primeiro objeto do *resultset* e então imprimir o atributo do ebjeto que você deseja na meta tag.

Comment: sim pois é, mas não ta rolando isso. hum.

Comment: Tente acessar o primeiro objeto da collection com: `$this->imagem[0]->getAtributo()`

Comment: é com isso imprime uma imagem do banco na tela, mas não a imagem certa, pega uma qualquer e joga a mesma imagem pra todas as páginas :T

Comment: mas de qualquer forma o og:image não está pegando a imagem que apareceu na meta tag.

Comment: Qual a meta tag que está sendo gerada?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31308/discussion-between-estacio-di-fabio-and-rodrigo-rigotti).

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução. Tive que reescrever a função addMeta() para que o parametro `name` fosse substituido por `property`.